# Python: Confused with list.remove

Tags: python, list

I'm very new to Python, so sorry for the probably simple question. 
(Although, I spent now 2 hours to find an answer)

I simplified my code to illustrate the problem:

```
side=[5]
eva=side
print(str(side) + " side before")
print(str(eva) + " eva before")
eva.remove(5)
print(str(side) + " side after")
print(str(eva) + " eva after")
```

This yields:

```
[5] side before
[5] eva before
[] side after
[] eva after
```

Why does the remove command also affects the list 'side'?  What can I do to use a copy of 'side', without modifying the list?

Thank you very much

Edit: Thank you very much for the good and comprehensible answers!

Comment: You've run into the idea of names in python. http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names

Comment: @GoingTharn *Namespaces* are a quite different matter. He's run into the fact that there are no value types in Python (and yes, that can be described in a gazillion other ways too - but "namespaces" isn't among them).

Comment: @delnan agreed; I realized with horror I'd written namespaces and edited to names. Dusan's link in the (current) top voted answer is better than mine anyhow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python has "things" and "names for things". When you write

```
side = [5]
```

you make a new thing `[5]`, and give it the name `side`. When you then write

```
eva = side
```

you make a new name for `side`. Assignments are just giving names to things! There's still only one thing `[5]`, with two different names.

If you want a new thing, you need to ask for it explicitly. Usually you would do `copy.copy(thing)`, although in the case of lists there's special syntax `thing[:]`.

<sub>FYI "things" are usually called "objects"; "names" are usually called "references".</sub>

Comment: The correct answer is that lists are mutable! Other Python objects (such as Strings) don't behave in this way...

Answer (score 11):

`eva` and `side` refer to the same list.

If you want to have a copy of the list:

```
eva = side[:]
```

You can read more about copying lists in this article: [Python: copying a list the right way](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list)

**Edit**: That isn't the only way to copy lists. See the link posted in the first comment of this answer.

Comment: There's also the excellent answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-a-list-in-python/2612815#2612815.

Comment: Or, from the article eva = list(side)

Answer (score 1):

[dusan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183791/dusan) answer is correct, and is a clever approach, but I think it breaks the Zen of Python guideline that *"Explicit is better than implicit."*

A far more common pattern I've seen to ensure an item is a deepcopy is with the `copy` module.

```
>>> import copy
>>> eva = copy.copy(side)
```

Comment: I don't think it breaks the explicitness guideline. It is _explicitly_ copying! Opaque syntax, maybe.

Comment: Also note `copy.copy` does the same as `[:]`, not `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: The two are different use cases.  You don't necessarily always want to make copies of the items in the list.

Comment: `side[:]` *is* idiomatic Python.

Comment: To back up my prior comment I `os.walk`'d all python files in the Python 2.7 source Lib directory.  In 1,540 files, `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy` were used 132 times.  `[:]` appeared 441 times, but was used to copy 176 times.  So `[:]` is no less idiomatic than using `copy.copy`.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for that information!  It's refreshing to have frequency counts in semantic discussions like this.  To be honest, I had never seen `[:]` before now.  I would hazard that not everything in the stdlib is idiomatic (there are some awful practices hidden away in some libraries), but I totally agree with your claim that both are "idiomatic" after reading your counts.

Comment: @katrielalex, thanks for catching my `copy` vs `deepcopy` goof.